# curl call slows down debugger inside PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, curl, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm's PHP remote debugging configuration with PHP xDebug extension on a wamp server, which is working just fine.

However, I noticed an issue when there is a `curl_exec` call, which is supposed to call my dummy API, also part of the project. The issue is, that, after the curl_exec call, there is around 30 seconds timeout period before debugger would jump to the breakpont defined inside an API method. This could make more sense:

```
    index.php                API
-----------------     --------------------
|                 |   |   API_Method() {  |
|  curl_exec( )   | ->|     breakpoint    |
|                 |   |    }              |
 -----------------     -------------------
```

Without using debugging, curl automatically returns back result from API_Method() and application is running just fine. However when I set a breakpoint inside the API_Method(), I have to wait around 30 secons before debugger jumps to that breakpoint which is becoming annoying. This is xdebug configuration:

```
[xdebug]

debug.remote_host
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
debug.remote_host= 192.168.23.55
xdebug.trace_output_name = cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
```

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` -- the debugger is set to attempt to automatically debug every script (as required to debug such scenario). Possibly it is connected to debugger (but you do not see it) .. and after 30 secs delay web server (or PHP itself) just kills that  script? **P.S.** I assume that `debug.remote_host` is done on purpose or accidentally (while creating ticket) and it is not like that in actual config file (especially first entry) .. as correct name should be `xdebug.remote_host`

Comment: Actually, debug was a typo, thanks for noticing that, but changing it to xdebug didn't make any progress. I'm not sure that API script is killed, because after the period of 30 seconds debugging actually works there...

Comment: Well ... I may only suggest to collect xdebug logs and see what it may say there: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . I personally have not faced such behaviour when was doing similar kind of debugging (although it was on Windows platform under local IIS server; have not done like that under Linux/Apache)

Comment: This issue is not Linux specific, it is present in both Windows and Linux environments. Here is more info: I checked and you were right, API script is actually killed after ~30 seconds, I noticed that because at around the same time result is returned and debugger jumps to the specific breakpoint, which is weird because that method already returned result. However, debugging works just fine if I access API URL directly, without going though the index.php which calls curl, which calls API. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look for inside the log file?

Comment: I can only guess that for some reason xdebug blocks curl call, and after 30 seconds just continues executing it, nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: After some thinking it occurred to me that it might be calling API from curl that is causing all this headache. The thing is, URL that curl is calling, will create new HTTP request that will go through WAMP and xdebug would be alerted. However, xdebug would already be up from the previous request that goes though index.php...

Comment: How many simultaneous debug session do you have allowed in IDE? By defaults it's only one. Maybe increasing the number to 2 or more will do any better for you? `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug --> Max. simultaneous connections` Also -- what did xdebug log said?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing max connections didn't fixed the issue. I'll try to analyze the logs..